# Is it normal for my dog to be sick after worming?

Tags: dogs, health

I have a 11 month old female Weimaraner and every time we worm her she gets quite sick. Symptoms are lethargy and vomiting (usually she vomits only once).

We are currently using Panoramis Brown (27.1kg-54kg) but she only weighs 26kg, this is what the vet recommended. We had previously used Advocate but we switched because it was making her sick. We also worm her during the day on weekends so we can watch her, and never on an empty stomach.

Is it normal for dogs to be sick after worming? Should I try a different worming tablet?

Comment: What did your vet say about the Advocate making her sick? Does the vet know that you changed the worming medication?

Comment: We told the vet the Advocate was making her sick, so he recommended we try Panoramis. Initially we were using Panoramis Green (up to 18kg) which was OK (no vomiting, just lethargy), but she quickly outgrew it so we switched to the Brown when she hit 25kg. I'm not sure if we should try something else, I know Weimaraners are typically more sensitive than other breeds.

Comment: *"every time we worm her"* Is this actually for prevention or as a therapy? With about 11 month it should just be her second time if you want to do it for prevention? Or maybe there's some detail I'm missing?

Comment: "Panoramis tablets are administered orally once a month at the recommended dosage". The recommended dosage is one tablet. So we have been worming her once a month as directed. Is monthly too often?

Comment: No, if it's really a monthly dosage, it's fine. In Germany some recommend a therapy working on a six months interval, didn't expect anything shorter for prevention only.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [label information on Panoramis](https://www.elancocentral.com/PanoramisLabel.pdf)

> In some animals, PANORAMIS may be associated with vomiting, commonly within 48 hours of administration of the first dose and decreasing in incidence with repeat doses. If vomiting occurs within an hour of administration, re-dose with another full dose.

Additionally,

> The following adverse events have been recorded following administration of spinosad and milbemycin oxime [the ingredients of Panoramis] together: vomiting, pruritis, lethargy, and diarrhea.

The label also indicates that there is a dose for dogs 18.1 - 27 kg (though it doesn't say what color it is). It contains 810 mg spinosad and 13.5 mg milbemycin oxime.

I would definitely suggest getting the correct dose for your dog's weight, but not to be too concerned about the vomiting.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can happen.

One thing I may suggest is if your dog doesn't have many intestinal worms every time you use Panoramis, you can wait 2-3 months instead of doing it every month. **EDIT: That is, if you use Panoramis for intestinal worms. Heartworm require monthly treatment.**

*"After six months all dogs need to be wormed every three months for effective protection"*
http://www.vetwest.com.au/pet-library/caring-for-your-dog-vaccinations-worming-flea-heartworm-feeding

If you want to try another excellent brand, I can suggest you to use Strongid but it won't prevent heartworms. If you want to prevent heartworms, you can ask your veterinarian about Ivomec, and for heartworm you do need to use it every month.

Comment: This answer suggests adjusting medications to other than prescribed/recommended intervals without providing rational nor supporting references. -1 until validated with reliable references.

Comment: As mentioned, if she uses the product for heatworms prevention, it's usually every month.

If it's for intestinal worms, it can bet done every 3 months unless the dogs has worms and the owner can see it.

"Common worms are readily controllable with a routine worming treatment. Puppies should be wormed every two weeks until twelve weeks of age, then monthly until six months of age. After six months all dogs need to be wormed every three months for effective protection."
http://www.vetwest.com.au/pet-library/caring-for-your-dog-vaccinations-worming-flea-heartworm-feeding

Comment: Much improved by your reference +1